# Javascript setInterval Loop variable not holding

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
 while(dataSet.size()>0){
      var data = dataSet.dequeue();
      intervalId = setInterval(function(){ 
      loadPointsEverySecond(data)}, updateInterval);
    }}
```

The dataset is a Queue of data JSON Objects. This data json object contains different points and they have to access at a particular interval one after the other. But only the last item in the dataset is accessed in loadPointsEverySecond in all the calls

Comment: infamous for loop

Comment: Why on earth you want to create hundred intervals?

Comment: It's a scenario i create  which i am facing similar

Comment: Hmm... a horror scenario, please read how [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) works.

Comment: @epascarello I have updated the question please remove duplicate